# Is the collection of hyperplane separating vectors Borel-measurable?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $C\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be non-empty, convex, such that $0\notin C$. Let $$H=\{\alpha\in\mathbb R^d\mid\alpha\cdot c\geq 0 \text{ for all } c\in C\text{ and }\alpha\cdot c_0>0 \text{ for some } c_0\in C\}.$$ By the separation theorem in $\mathbb R^d$ we know that $H$ is non-empty. Is $H$ Borel-measurable, or even closed? I call $H$ the collection of hyperplane separating vectors since each $\alpha\in H$ is perpendicular to a hyperplane which separates $0$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be arbitrary dense subset of $C$, then 
$$
H=\{\alpha\in\mathbb R^d\mid\alpha\cdot c\geq 0 \text{ for all } c\in S\text{ and }\alpha\cdot c_0>0 \text{ for some } c_0\in S\}
$$
For each $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ define a continuous function $f_x:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}:\alpha\mapsto\alpha\cdot x$, so
$$
H=\left(\bigcap_{c\in S}f_c^{-1}([0,+\infty))\right)\bigcap\left(\bigcup_{c\in S}f_c^{-1}((0,+\infty))\right)
$$
Since $\mathbb{R}^d$ is separable, so does $C\subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Choose $S$ to be countable dense subset $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $C$, then
$$
H=\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_{c_n}^{-1}([0,+\infty))\right)\bigcap\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_{c_n}^{-1}((0,+\infty))\right)
$$
Now it is obvious that $H$ is a Borel-measurable.

Take $C=\{e_1\}$ to see that $H$ is not necessarily closed.

Comment: no, becasue you operate with countable amount of points $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset C$